# Joomla being redirected to www without any redirection

Tags: linux, nginx, joomla

My joomle site live2.joomlaabc.com redirectes to www.live2.joomlaabc.com , even though there is no nginx directive that performs this 301 redirection. Does joomla has any redirection like this in its configuration?

I just cloned the website joomlaabc.com to live2.joomlaabc.com , as i want to test its copy on another server, but main server works fine (joomlaabc.com, redirectes to www.joomlaabc.com) but live2 also redirects to joomlaabc.com.

In configuration.php i have set the url to http://live2.joomlaabc.com as well , but still it keeps redirection to www.

Comment: Your domain's DNS seems to be broken. This may contribute to the problem you are seeing. Get the DNS back up and running first.

Comment: i m using cloudflare, and on it, i have pointed that url to an IP

Comment: so what do you mean by broken?

Comment: @Farhan Neither joomlaabc.com nor live2.joomlaabc.com resolve from the Internet.

Comment: Your domain is _not_ correctly set up for CloudFlare. You need to [set the correct nameservers with your domain registrar](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708).

Comment: actuallay they are dummy domains, i cannot provide real domains for privacy reasons

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a browser side redirect.

It is common for browsers to add `www.` to URLs that don't include `www.` and are don't have a server available.  This allows users to enter `example.com` and get servered the `www.example.com` site.

Verify that the domain of your Joomla site resolves on the host that is getting redirected.  Try using `nslookup` or `host` from the command line.  If you have telnet or putty on your host, you can try connection to port 80 (HTTP) or port 443 (HTTPS) as a telnet session.

Sites like isup.me can be used to see if your site resolves from the internet.

Comment: there is an IP pointed to it on cloudflare , like this: live2.joomlaabc.com 56.87.98.33